# SQLite Database Table is not accessibe

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am downloading sqlite database from the server and storing on the device.
But when tring to access the tables it shows error
**android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: Foods (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR)**: , while compiling: SELECT Date_Time, Food, Calories FROM Foods

When trying to access the table using SQLiteBrowser it is accessible.

```
public class calorieChart extends AppCompatActivity {

    Integer entries=600;

    @Override
    protected void  onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.user_otp);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume(){   
        super.onResume();
        SharedPreferences 
        sharedPreferences=this.getSharedPreferences("AppPreferences",MODE_PRIVATE);
        String mobile=sharedPreferences.getString("userMobileNumber","") ;
        String filekey=mobile+".db";
        SQLiteDatabase db=SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase("/data/data/com.dieto.nutri/files/"+filekey,null,SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Foods1 (Date_Time TEXT ,Food Text ,Calories INTEGER);");

        String Cols[]={"Date_Time","Food","Calories"};
        Cursor foods_cursor=db.query("Foods",Cols,null,null,null,null,null);
        ArrayList<String> date_Time=new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> food_item=new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> calories=new ArrayList<>();
        int i=0;
        Toast.makeText(calorieChart.this,foods_cursor.getString(1).toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        if(foods_cursor.moveToFirst()){
            do{
            date_Time.add(foods_cursor.getString(0));
            calories.add(foods_cursor.getString(2));
            food_item.add(foods_cursor.getString(1));
            i=i+1;
            }while(foods_cursor.moveToNext()&&i<entries);
        }
        foods_cursor.close();
    }
}
```

---

```
String filekey=mobile+".db";
File file;

Amplify.Storage.downloadFile(
    filekey,
    file=new File(getApplicationContext().getFilesDir()+"/"+filekey),
    result->Log.i("Myamplifyapp","File downloaded "+result.getFile().getName()),
    error->Log.i("Myamplifyapp","File download Failed",error)
);

if(!file.exists()){
    try{
        file.createNewFile();
        Toast.makeText(userOtpActivity.this,"File Created",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(userOtpActivity.this,e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The create statement names the table **Foods1** not **Foods** as is the table name used later and hence why the table **Foods** is not found.

Comment: Hi Mike! Foods Table is found in the downloaded file(I verified through SQLiteBrowser) .Food1 is just creating another file.

Comment: @RajendiranS Not as far as SQLite is concerned. Suggest you do `Cursor csr = db.query("sqlite_master",null,null,null,null,null,null);` followed by `DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(csr);` and then check the log.

Comment: Got it resolved.Actually file is in downloading status so when checking for file it produced error.Tried after file downloaded confirmation, it works like a charms!Thanks mike! :)